# Sum per day, week and month

Tags: php, mysql

I do have a table with a field called "hours", that field is the time that my workers works per day, it creates a new registry for each day, so it's something like this:

```
Date: 2017-02-06; hours: 3
Date: 2017-02-07; hours: 8
Date: 2017-02-31; hours: 8
```

The question is, how can i do a select to sum all the hours for this day(that's already solved), for this week and for this month.

What I expect is this:

sum for this day(2017-02-06): 3

sum for this week(2017-02-06-2017--2017-02-12): 11

sum for this month (february): 19

Original query:

```
$db->query("select sum(hours) horasDia from table_hours where                                                            
user="'.$user.'" and DATE(inici)=date('Y-m-d'));
```

I'm doing this via php.

EDIT:
With the answer of rahul_m:

For day,

```
SELECT    SUM(`hours`) horasDia
FROM      table_hours 
WHERE     user="'.$user.'" and DATE(inici)= your_date;
```

For week,

```
SELECT    SUM(`hours`) horasDia
FROM      table_hours 
WHERE     user="'.$user.'" and DATE(inici)= your_date;
GROUP BY  WEEK(your_date);
```

For month

```
SELECT    SUM(`hours`) horasDia
FROM      table_hours 
WHERE     user="'.$user.'" and DATE(inici)= your_date;
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(your_date, "%m-%Y");
```

In the week section it's giving me only the hours of the date 2017-01-31 (2017-01-30 week)

```
SELECT    SUM(`hours`) horasDia
FROM      table_hours 
WHERE     user="'.$user.'" and DATE(inici)= "2017-01-31";
GROUP BY  WEEK("2017-01-31");
```

In the month section, it's giving me just nothing.

```
SELECT    SUM(`hours`) horasDia
FROM      table_hours 
WHERE     user="'.$user.'" and DATE(inici)= "2017-01-31";
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT("2017-01-31", "%m-%Y");
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output

Comment: and show your query that work (by day)

Comment: week for that date will give data for dates belongs to that day only, I hope I am clear,

Comment: I got it! It was my bad t.t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For day,

```
SELECT    SUM(`hours`) horasDia
FROM      table_hours 
WHERE     user="'.$user.'" and DATE(inici)= your_date;
```

For week,

```
SELECT    SUM(`hours`) horasDia
FROM      table_hours 
WHERE     user="'.$user.'" and DATE(inici)= your_date;
GROUP BY  WEEK(your_date);
```

For month

```
SELECT    SUM(`hours`) horasDia
FROM      table_hours 
WHERE     user="'.$user.'" and DATE(inici)= your_date;
GROUP BY  YEAR(o_date), MONTH(o_date)
```

You will get all three details as per your requirements with this,
give it a try.

**EDIT**

Week's related data is correct, as it is giving all data of that week only.

For months,

For month

```
SELECT    SUM(`hours`) horasDia
FROM      table_hours 
WHERE     user="'.$user.'" and DATE(inici)= your_date;
GROUP BY  YEAR(your_date), MONTH(your_date)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not working for me so far, in the week the data used in the where clause is the same that is used in the group by? And by it's not working i mean in the week it's not doing well the sum thing, and in the month it shows me nothing.